# Fetching value from a datatable into datatable with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `datatable` ***dtTable***, in which there are several columns, one of which is called ***Value***.

The ***Value*** column is of type `int64`, and has the following values:

```
12356
0
78
4
0
```

Now i want to fetch those rows whose values in the ***Value*** column is greater then zero. I.e, I want the following rows from the example above:

```
12356
78
4
```

I think linq would be appropriate for this type of situation, any solution would be helpful.

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please read it rephrase it

Comment: `SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS 'myVal' FROM myTable WHERE VALUE > 0;`?

Comment: @user5173426 why sum ?

Comment: pffty I thought he meant to `SUM` those values :3

Comment: @Amit No its not Database Table its DataTable.

Comment: @Eldho Rephrased the question, can you help now?

Comment: @JiteshDammani `tblFiltered = table.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(row => row.Field<int>("Value") >0`

Comment: @Eldho sorry the datatype is int64, its giving the following error 'Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = db.dtTable.Where(x=> x.Value > 0).ToList();
```

*OP: No its not Database Table its DataTable.*

```
DataTable filteredTable = dtTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("Value") > 0).CopyToDataTable();
```

*OP: sorry the datatype is int64, its giving the following error 'Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type.'*

```
DataTable filteredTable = dtTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<Int64?>("Value") > 0).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: i want a data table to be fetched from original data table with the above condition not only the value column

Comment: sorry the datatype is int64, its giving the following error 'Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type.'

Comment: @JiteshDammani edited the answer!

Comment: 'Specified cast is not valid' error :(

Comment: try `Convert.ToInt32();` or `Convert.ToInt64();` instead?

Comment: Its working is i change the datatable datatype to int32. Thanks :)

Comment: your last edited answer indicating Int64 is incorrect , You are casting it to standard Int only. May be the OP changed his field in Database but for the asked question your answer is slightly wrong

Comment: @DharaniKumar good catch, corrected.

Comment: Still the Case is incorrect :) , it's Int64, I would have edited it but edit should be more than 6 characters.

Comment: @DharaniKumar Ha! this is what happens when you miss your sleep!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = dtTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(r => r.Field<Int>("Value") > 0)
                             .CopyToDataTable();
```

where Value is your column name with datatype int.

By the way a simple googling would have solved your query.

OP: it's a 64 bit Integer and can be null:

```
 DataTable tblFiltered = dtTable.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => r.Field<Int64?>("Value") > 0)
                                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: sorry the datatype is int64, its giving the following error 'Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type.'

Comment: Since i am not sure of what you're asking , Based on my understanding you're trying to query based on  a Int64 field which can also be null

In that case:  

   DataTable tblFiltered = dtTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(r => r.Field<Int64?>("Value") > 0)
                             .CopyToDataTable();

But i would suggest you set a default value for the field in Database side

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean ? show your result with sample data. And Currently, I am understanding like this. Please try this:

```
  select t.* from table t where t.value > 0
```

Comment: if you are not clear what OP is asking, wait till clarification from OP himself.

Comment: This is for database table, i want it for datatable